# Kohana parameterised execution of query within view

Tags: database, model-view-controller, kohana, prepared-statement

I'm just trying to get my head around Kohana, so if I'm going about this the wrong way, let me know!

I want to group results in my output. The way I did this in vanilla-PHP / PDO was to prepare a query, and then execute it within the output results. I can't get there in Kohana (3.2.2), though.

In this case, on my 'terms' page, I want to group 'terms' by 'type', with each group of terms separated by a 'type' header.

My 'terms' controller is (simplified):

```
class Controller_Terms extends Controller {

  public function action_index() 
  {
    $view = View::factory('terms');

    // types of term - for grouping terms together
    $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT Type 
            FROM Term';
    $view->types = DB::query(Database::SELECT, $sql)->as_object()->execute();

    // list of terms - executed separately for each type
    $sql = 'SELECT TermId, Term
            FROM Term
            WHERE Type = :type';
    $view->terms = DB::query(Database::SELECT, $sql)->as_object();

    $this->response->body($view);
  }

}
```

And the 'terms' view includes (simplified):

```
<? foreach ($types as $type): ?>
<h2><?= $type->Type ?></h2>
<? $params = array(':type' => $type->Type);
   $terms->parameters($params)->execute(); 
   foreach ($terms as $term): ?>
    <a href="term/<?= $term->TermId ?>"><?= $term->Term ?></a>
<? endforeach // term ?>
<? endforeach // type ?>
```

I get the 'type' headers ok, but I don't get any terms within each type.

Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`execute()` [returns](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/database/query/prepared#executing) a special object (`Database_Result`), so you need something like this:

```
$items = $terms->parameters($params)->execute(); 
foreach ($items as $term): ?>
...
```

Comment: I think you shouldn't execute queries from the view. Views are for presentation logic, not for business logic. Also, you can replace `foreach` with one query (select * from term where type in ... order by type).